# React/JS gets stuck: weird bug I can't solve

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am a beginner with React, JS, and I wrote a simple, ten-line program that tracks clicks in a web document and displays their positions in a text element.

It seems simple, and it works as intended, but only for seven clicks, after which the program locks up and will not execute any more, and won't display the positions of new clicks, and the page will not even update.

This exact thing happens whether I run it from my local Chrome and Safari or if I run it inside an online sandbox.

What could be causing this issue? How should I diagnose this kind of an issue?

Here is the code:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState({ x: 1, y: 1 });

  function handleClick(e) {
    setCoordinates({ x: e.screenX, y: e.screenY });
  }
  document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

  return (
    <p>
      x: {coordinates.x}, y: {coordinates.y};
    </p>
  );
}
```

The sandbox with code is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-sea-0vmq12?file=/src/App.js:0-401).

I appreciate any suggestions and apologize if I am making a very obvious mistake.

Comment: I'm sorry for the bad formatting, I fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for updating. That's much better!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you register a new *click* event listener every time the component renders.

Event listeners, like any side-effect should be registered in an [effect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html). They should also be un-registered using the clean-up return value

```js
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);

  // cleanup
  return () => document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
}, []);
```

[image: Edit lucid-tamas-yr3zvs]

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping the `document.addEventListener()` inside a `useEffect` with empty dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  document.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
}, [])
```

That way, you only invoke the addEventListener once (at component mount) and not every time the component re-renders.